# Automatically insert recipient name in WhatsApp's broadcast message

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have a broadcast list of about 115 and would like to send a broadcast message on WhatsApp and personalise the message to each person.

The message would read:

> Hi `<Name>`, thanks for spending time with us. Have a good day further.

I know there are codes for fonts and text effects but if anyone knows of a code that would allow me to do this I will be very grateful.

Comment: AFAIK, WhatsApp only supports [simple text formatting](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000002/), so for more complex automation like this, perhaps 3rd-party apps are needed (not yet researched though).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the custom WhatsApp broadcast tool for web.

It automates sending of custom message uploaded in a csv using web.whatsapp.com

Link to the program
https://whats-app-dialer.com/#broadcasthtml